# why am I receiving error starting microclimate on macos stating TLS handshake timeout

Tags: microclimate

I've successfully completed the ./install.sh command. When I run the next "~/mcdev start -o" I receive this error: "Starting Microclimate

Pulling microclimate-file-watcher (ibmcom/microclimate-file-watcher:1809)...
ERROR: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ibmcom/microclimate-file-watcher/manifests/1809: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Error starting Microclimate"

I have running on my pc:

- git version 2.17.1 (Apple Git-112); Docker version 18.06.1-ce;  MacOS
  High Sierra v 10.13.6; latest Microclimate v18.09

My network is up and I don't have any proxy.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: installed locally; without ICP

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by changing to a different wifi \ internet connection. Still not sure why my home wifi, with no restrictions that I'm aware of, will 'block' the dependency downloads upon start of Microclimate. 
If anybody has additional info to help find the root cause please feel free to share.

Answer (score 0):

This docker error generally shows up when your internet connection is too slow for Docker, as it times out performing the TLS handshake. This would also explain why moving to another network fixes the issue.